# How to use one of the outputs of a subroutine as a function?

Tags: function, pointers, fortran, assign, subroutine

I'm working in Fortran and I'm trying to use one of the outs of a subroutine as a function and operate with it, but I can't figure out how to do it right. Here is a test program of what I'm trying to do

```
module funciones
 use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
 implicit none

type ptr_wrapper
  procedure(f), nopass, pointer :: func
end type ptr_wrapper

abstract interface
function f(x1,x2)
   import
   real(dp), intent(in) :: x1,x2
   real(dp) :: f
 end function f
end interface

abstract interface
 subroutine g(x,y,f1,f2)
import
real(dp), intent(in) :: x,y
real(dp), intent(out) :: f1,f2
end subroutine g
end interface

contains 
 subroutine test_func(x,y,f1,f2)
 real(dp), intent(in) :: x,y
 real(dp), intent(out) :: f1,f2

 f1 = x*y
 f2 = 2d0*x+5d0*y

 end subroutine test_func

 function Derivate (x,y,fx) result (d)
    implicit none
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x,y
    procedure(f), pointer :: fx
    real(dp) :: d

    real(dp) :: h = 1.0E-6

    d = (1.0*fx(x-2*h,y) - 8.0*fx(x-h,y) + 8.0*fx(x+h,y) -   1.0*fx(x+2*h,y))/(12.0*h)
end function Derivate


function separation1(x,y,F_in) result(DF_out1)
    implicit none
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x,y
    procedure(g) :: F_in
    real(dp) :: F_out1, F_out2
    real(dp) :: DF_out1
    procedure (f), pointer:: F1_ptr
    Call F_in (x,y,F_out1,F_out2)
    F1_ptr => F_out1
    DF_out1 = Derivate(x,y,F1_ptr)
end function separation1

function separation2(x,y,F_in) result(F_out2)
    implicit none
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x,y
    procedure(g) :: F_in
    real(dp) :: F_out1, F_out2
    Call F_in (x,y,F_out1,F_out2)
end function separation2


 end module funciones

program testsubroutines
 use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
 use funciones
 implicit none


 print*, separation1(1d0,3d0,test_func)
 print*, separation2(1d0,3d0,test_func)



end program testsubroutines
```

So basically this program creates to test functions (with the subroutine) and then separates the outs. The function separates2 work ok so I decided to make a step forward and implement in separate1 the function that derives it. But I can't figure out how to assign the  pointer to the out and I always get an error in that line.

I tried also creating two pointers

```
F1_ptr,F2_ptr
```

and assigning them as

```
(F1_ptr,F2_ptr)=>Call F_in(x,y,F_out1,F_out2)
```

but I get

```
Error : Unclassifiable assignment at (1).
```

If I assign the value as

```
F1_ptr => F_out1
```

I get the error message

```
Error: Invalid procedure pointer assignment at (1)
```

or if I do

```
F1_ptr %func => Call F_in (x,y,F_out1,F_out2)
             1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

and

```
DF_out1 = Derivate(x,y,F1_ptr)
                     1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘fx’ at (1); passed TYPE(ptr_wrapper) to REAL(8)
```

I also tried these two changes

```
...
abstract interface
subroutine g(x,y,f1,f2)
import
real(dp), intent(in) :: x,y
procedure(f),pointer :: f1,f2
end subroutine g
end interface

contains 
subroutine test_func(x,y,f1,f2)
real(dp), intent(in) :: x,y
type (ptr_wrapper) :: f1,f2
f1%func => x*y
f2%func => 2d0*x+5d0*y
```

...

but I get

```
 f1%func => x*y
        1
 Error: Invalid procedure pointer assignment at (1)
```

and the same error message for f2

So, how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "outs" the output? This is not an established shortcut. It is better to avoid slang, at least in the title and first mention.

Comment: *"and I always get an error in that line."* You should report the error.

Comment: In a subroutine, at least in fortran, you can have more than one out, in difference as a function that only can have one. So I create a subroutine which in my case has two outs and I want to operate with one of them as a function. Any modification in the title is welcome

Comment: I edited to add the error messages. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to describe the reason for an edit in the question. When you make an edit there is place for a comment. You can describe the reason there. Also, we try to keep the questions concise and don't include any greetings or thanks.

Comment: I'd like that the outputs of the subroutine be functions, or something that can be used in other functions. That is ,f1 for example, can be an argument of Derivate. That's why in the last try I posted I made (or at least I tried to make) the outputs of the subroutine functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subroutine `test_func` has two dummy arguments that let the subroutine report two **values** that result from some computations inside the subroutine.

In Fortran, **values are not functions**.

(This distinction is blurred, or eliminated, in some other languages, but not in Fortran.)

In Fortran, a value is something that might result when a function is invoked, but there is a difference between invoking a function and the function itself.

The intention behind the question is not clear to me, but if you want to expose the calculations that are inside the subroutine `test_func` (as an aside - putting "func" in the name of a subroutine is rather confusing) as a function, then you need to write a function that calls `test_func`, passing the output argument of interest back as the function result.  Such a function is pretty simple, it could be something like:

```
function get_f1_from_test_func(x, y) result(f1)
  real(dp), intent(in) :: x
  real(dp), intent(in) :: y
  real(dp) :: f1
  real(dp) :: ignored
  call test_func(x, y, f1, ignored)
end function get_f1_from_test_func
```

That function returns the value of the `f1` dummy argument in `test_func`.  If you want the `f2` argument instead, write another function.

```
function get_f2_from_test_func(x, y) result(f2)
  real(dp), intent(in) :: x
  real(dp), intent(in) :: y
  real(dp) :: f2
  real(dp) :: ignored
  call test_func(x, y, ignored, f2)
end function get_f2_from_test_func
```

The above two functions are consistent with the interface of the function required by the `fx` dummy argument of Derivate.

As indicated by the names of the local variables in the above wrapper functions, the result in one of the output dummy arguments of `test_func` will be discarded when a wrapper function is invoked.  This is unlikely to be computationally efficient, but this situation is a consequence of the two computations being bundled together in `test_func`.